# Redux Toolkit RTK Query useMutation and keep cached data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

According to the documentation : `'Subscribes' the component to keep cached data in the store, and 'unsubscribes' when the component unmounts`.

Is there a way to keep the cache of mutation everywhere and not 'unsubscribe' it ? I mean that I can call `useMutation` in differents components and get the cached data and the status sync across all these components (like the queries). Because for now, I will lost the data as soon as a component has unmount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently, but there is a ongoing Pull Request that will make it into the next minor release.

You can tack it here:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pull/1477

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested the preview version with this : `yarn add https://pkg.csb.dev/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/commit/b06b0529/@reduxjs/toolkit`.  But it doesn't seem to work. I don't get the data if I am using the `useMutation` hook in an other component. However, I have the `reset` function. Is it normal ?

Comment: I also tested with the last preview version : `yarn add https://pkg.csb.dev/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/commit/afd23267/@reduxjs/toolkit`. But no success. I found the link [here](https://ci.codesandbox.io/status/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pr/1476/builds/166183).  I don't know if it's possible to install locally a preview version to get it work ?

Comment: The builds from https://ci.codesandbox.io/status/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/pr/1477/builds/166224 are the right ones. It's not 100% finished yet and will have to be used a bit differently. You'll have to specify a cache key by yourself by calling `useMyMutation({ fixedCacheKey: "myCacheKey" })`. A cache entry specified like that will not be cleaned up automatically and you can use multiple components to access it.

Comment: Thank you. It works now with the `fixedCacheKey` property so I will using this build. Do you know approximately when it will be available in a public release ?

Comment: I'd guess a month or two. The next release will have SSR support, rehydration support and `fixedCacheKey`. All of these are "kinda done", but need detail work and I don't have a lot of time at the moment.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks.